# Does Batch Size matter if I only care about deploying and not training?

Tags: deep-learning, gpu

Gonna ask a newbie question...

If I finished training my model, or I am using trained model like YOLO. And I want to put the model on a robot that has a 6GB VRAM. In this case, do I need to concern about the batch size at all?

I am trying to find out if models like YOLO will fit in my GPU.
Thank you

Comment: This question belongs to https://ai.stackexchange.com/, not really onto StackOverflow. That being said, for most architectures you can change the batch size arbitrarily for a trained model, so the answer is it does not matter.

Comment: Then what is preventing me from deploying a huge object detection model on a, say 1 GB Vram GPU? It is the size of the input? the number of parameters?

Comment: Roughly speaking the product of the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, batch size can be adjusted at any time without creating a problem. Each element of a batch is independent, but they are fed through the network together for efficiency reasons.

Note that batch size does affect training quality, as the gradients from larger batches will average out and have less variance. But that is irrelevant when doing inference (actually using the model).

You also asked what prevents you deploying a huge model on a small GPU, and the answer is simply performance. It is entirely *possible* to load part of a large model onto the GPU, run that part, load the next part, run it, and so on. You would need to balance the batch size and model part size, because if you only use a batch size of 1, the continual copying of model parameters will probably make it slower than running the whole model on the CPU.